# Replacing Values in Yaml file using Sed cmd

Tags: awk, sed, yaml

I have the below YAML file

```
Test:  '5.3.4.7'
Cloudmode:  'Azure'
```

I want to replace the value of Test .i.e. '5.3.4.7' to '6.3.4.7'

Below is what I have got, it is replacing the value but it's not displaying in a different line. I also don't want to hardcode "5.3.4.7" value. Any advice, please?

```
sed -i -e  \'s/5.3.4.7/\'${version}\'\\n/\' -e $\'s/cloudmode/\\\n cloudmode/g\' defaults.yaml
```

Comment: IMHO experts always advice to use those tools which understand yaml files, since awk and sed are not best tools for it, so removed  those tags and added `yq` tag in it now.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: While what you did is right, please check with OP if they can use tool like `yq`, then if they can make it work add the tag. It might turn out that they can't use another tool than what they asked for

Comment: Please do let us know if using `yq` is feasible for you? If not then kindly do mention in your question so that users could provide `awk` or `sed` related answers then.

Comment: Using yq: `yq write defaults.yaml Test 6.3.4.7 -i --style single`

Comment: @Shawn: Please mention that `yq` is mikeferah yq. There is another version floating around called kilyusk `yq`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: i'm passing the cmd through a Jenkins pipeline and i can't install yq. Any other suggestion please?

Comment: *I also don't want to hardcode "5.3.2.7"* Then why don't you put something like `"%VERSION%"` there if you're gonna replace it anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following `awk` + `tac` solution, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Since OP mentioned that OP couldn't use `yq` so adding this solution.

There is an `awk` variable named `new_version` which will have new version which OP needs in output, you could later change version number there as per your need and need not to edit main block of code.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk -v s1="'" -v new_version="6.3.4.7" '
/Cloudmode.*Azure/{
  found=1
  print
  next
}
found{
  $NF=s1 new_version s1
  found=""
}
1
' | tac
```

---

---

In case you are Happy with above and want to inplace save into Input_file then use following.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk -v s1="'" -v new_version="6.3.4.7" '
/Cloudmode.*Azure/{
  found=1
  print
  next
}
found{
  $NF=s1 new_version s1
  found=""
}
1
' | tac > temp && mv temp Input_file
```